# Adding strings to certain lines using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to do some formatting to some man pages and I need to add

```
] hfill \\
```

to certain headers. I want to make this

```
NAME
   env - run a program in a modified environment

SYNOPSIS
   env    [-]    [-i]    [-u   name]   [--ignore-environment]
   [--unset=name] [name=value]... [command [args...]]

DESCRIPTION
   This manual page documents the GNU version  of  env.   env
   runs  a  command with an environment modified as specified
   by the command line...
```

into this

```
\item[NAME] \hfill \\
   env - run a program in a modified environment

\item[SYNOPSIS] \hfill \\
   env    [-]    [-i]    [-u   name]   [-\hspace{.01cm}-ignore-environment]
   [-\hspace{.01cm}-unset=name] [name=value]... [command [args...]]

\item[DESCRIPTION] \hfill \\
   This manual page documents the GNU version  of  env.   env
   runs  a  command with an environment modified as specified
   by the command line...
```

I got the "\item[" part down but I can't get the other half for whatever reasons. The command I'm using:

```
 /[A-Z]/s/$/\] \\hfill \\\\/
```

works but shows up on lines I don't want.

Comment: The regex `/[A-Z]/` matches any line with a capital letter.  Did you want it to be `/^\\item\[[A-Z]/` so that it only matches a capital letter that follows `\item[`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming header ar only line starting with a capital letter

```
sed '/^[A-Z]/ s/.*/\\item[&] \\hfill \\\\/' YourFile
```

for the `\hspace{.01cm}`, you shold define when it should occur (condition for)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^[[:upper:]]\+$/\\item[&] \\hfill \\\\/;s/\[--/[-\\hspace{.01cm}-/g' file
```

If you do not have GNU sed, try:

```
sed -e 's/^[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]*$/\\item[&] \\hfill \\\\/' -e 's/\[--/[-\\hspace{.01cm}-/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/^([A-Z]+)$/\\item[\1] \\hfill \\\\/' file.txt
```

you can do it by one step.